# Wordpress single.php second query pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination, infinite-scroll

I created a single.php Wordpress template file to show standard WP Posts.

This is the truncated version of the code:

```
<?php 
// First (Main Content) Loop
if (have_posts()) : 
  while (have_posts()):the_post();  
  ?>

  <div class="entry-content">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>    

  <?php 
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php
// Second (Related Posts) Loop

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
  'category__in' => 3,
  'posts_per_page'=> 4,
  'paged' => $paged
);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new wp_query($args);

if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>  

  <?php
  endwhile; 

  echo '<div id="navigation">'.get_next_posts_link('Load More').'</div>'; 

endif;
}

$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

The 4 related posts are generated as expected and the `get_next_posts_link` generates a link to /post-name/page/2.

I'm using Paul Irish's [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) plugin to load page/2's posts into the container (Which is working fine on the archive- and index.php pages on the site).

Unfortunately when you click `get_next_posts_link` the same 4 posts are appended to the container.

Any ideas how to get this to work? 
I've tried a lot of other solutions on StackOverflow but so far none have worked.

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: The solution to this problem is most likely related with the infinite scroll plugin. If you deactivate it and click the next_posts_link does it work ok?